# Is it safe to delete build-cache from .android folder in Mac

Tags: android-studio

I'm running with low space on my mac and came across build-cache folder from .android using alot of space. So Will it be a problem if i delete it.?

I have installed OmniDiskSweeper app for searching the filesystem and the sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the build-cache folder from .android and didn't face any issues running both the android-studio and project.